# adding additional email addresses to user

Tags: joomla-3.x

I would like to add more email address fields to the user, this field is not mandatory, nor does it need to receive system notifications, just as storage.

would I just add more fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a profile plugin to add additional registration and profile fields. The official documentation is at: https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin

If you are uncomfortable editing XML files etc, then it may be easier to use a third party extension such as [Easy Profile](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/clients-a-communities/user-management/easy-profile) (commercial extension), [Joom Profile](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/clients-a-communities/user-management/joom-profile) (commercial extension) or even [Community Builder](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/clients-a-communities/communities/community-builder) (free but probably overkill for what you are after).